# Does $\mathbb N$ have a predecessor?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\mathbb N$ be the Von Neumann constructed natural numbers.

Does $\mathbb N$ have a predecessor?

**My try**

$$\mathbb N^*:=\mathbb N \backslash \{\varnothing\}$$

Let $p$ be a map

$$p:\mathbb N^* \to \mathbb N \\n \to \bigcup n$$

namely the predecessor map.

**Example**

$$p(3) = \bigcup 3 = \bigcup \{ \varnothing ,\{\varnothing \},\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing \}\}\} = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing \}\} = 2$$

**My try continuous**

$$p(\mathbb N)=\bigcup \mathbb N = \mathbb N$$ 
thus, 
$$p(\mathbb N) \notin \mathbb N$$

But it does not make sense, because $\mathbb N \notin \mathbb N$.

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee There it is. Sorry if I have not used the proper language.

Comment: it's more so people don't think it's a no effort given question, or a question that should be closed as it's a give me the answer only question, or maybe it could be a homework question. showing work at least shows you tried and makes any sticking points you may have to overcome apparent.

Comment: Nice edit,@Dante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The first infinite ordinal $\Bbb N$ (or better written $\omega$ in this context) is a [limit ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal), i.e. it has *no* (immediate) predecessor.

Comment: All the finite ordinals precede $\omega,$ but it has no *immediate* predecessor.

Comment: @bof Thank you for this remark. I assumed "predecessor" defined as the largest preceeding ordinal.

Comment: Very well, I have deleted my comment.  I'll take your word for it.  (I don't mean that sarcastically, only sincerely.)